# hiding elements after a button is clicked - angular2 - ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, angular2-template

I am still learning Angular2 and I currently can't find a solution for my problem. I am displaying 1-3 Tiers/Packages using the ngFor, which than looks like this [tiers in display mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCUKI.png). 
After I click the edit button I only want the clicked element to go into edit mode, currently all of them switch into edit mode, which looks like this [tiers in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoTeV.png).

Here is the code, reduced it to the relevant parts.

```
<h1 class="page-title"><span class="fw-semi-bold">Packages</span></h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers; let i=index;">
    <!-- Show Mode -->
    <ul [hidden]="editMode" class="pricing-table">
      <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }} {{i}}
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <p class="plan-price">{{ tier.price }}</p>
      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="this.onEdit()">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="this.clickSave()">SaveYes</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" >Get</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Edit Mode -->
    <ul [hidden]="!editMode" class="pricing-table-edit">
      <li class="plan-name-edit">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style=" font-size: 3rem;" placeholder="{{ tier.title }} " formControlName="package_name">

      </li>
      <li >
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46; ">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <div style="align:center; padding-left: 40%; padding-right: 40%;"><input type="text" id="package_price1" class="form-control plan-price" placeholder="4,99" formControlName="package_price"></div>

      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning">Publish</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Components-File:

```
export class PackagesComponent {
  editMode = false;

  onEdit () {
    this.editMode = true;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use the index variable in my method, so that I know which of the 3 tiers is currently clicked? Or are there any other solutions or maybe ideas?

Thanks a lot :)

**UPDATED CODE, thanks to Abrar:**

```
export class PackagesComponent {  //this has to be renamed to TierComponent for less confusion
  public tierToEdit: Tier;
  editMode = false;
  tiers: Tier[] = [
    new Tier(
      10,
      'First Tier',
      [
        {id: 500, title: 'desc', description: 'crazy description'},
        {id: 501, title: 'desc', description: 'crazy description'},
        {id: 502, title: 'desc', description: 'crazy description'},
        {id: 503, title: 'desc', description: 'crazy description'}
      ],
      5.00),
      *[more code..]*
  ]


  constructor (private tierService: TierService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  onEdit (tier: Tier) {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.tierToEdit = tier;
  }
```

Template-File:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><span class="fw-semi-bold">Packages</span></h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers; let i=index;">
    <!-- Show Mode -->
    <ul *ngIf="!editMode || tierToEdit != tier" class="pricing-table">
      <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }} {{i}}
      </li>
     <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }} {{i}}
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <li>
        description
      </li>
      <p class="plan-price">{{ tier.price }}</p>
      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit(tier)">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="this.clickSave()">SaveYes</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" >Get</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Edit Mode -->
    <ul *ngIf="editMode && tierToEdit == tier " class="pricing-table-edit">
      <li class="plan-name-edit">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style=" font-size: 3rem;" placeholder="{{ tier.title }} " formControlName="package_name">

      </li>
      <li >
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46; ">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
      </li>
      <div style="align:center; padding-left: 40%; padding-right: 40%;"><input type="text" id="package_price1" class="form-control plan-price" placeholder="4,99" formControlName="package_price"></div>

      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning">Publish</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't actually need to call `this.onEdit()` or `this.clickSave()` in the `(click)` event handler. Only `onEdit()` or `clickSave()` will work alright.

Notice here that you are not passing any reference to the clicked item which you want to go into edit mode. So, here you can either pass the index like this - `onEdit(i)` or the object like this - `onEdit(tier)`.

In your `PackagesComponent` you can set the `tier` that is clicked to a member variable -

```
export class PackagesComponent {
  public packageToEdit:Package;   // <------- new code

  editMode = false;

  onEdit (tier:Package) {
    this.packageToEdit = tier;    // <------- new code
    this.editMode = true;
  }
}
```

Now, in your HTML code

```
<!-- Edit Mode -->
<ul [hidden]="!editMode && packageToEdit==tier" class="pricing-table-edit">

  <li class="plan-name-edit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style=" font-size: 3rem;" placeholder="{{ tier.title }} " formControlName="package_name">

  </li>
  <li >
    <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46; ">Feature 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="rewards-edit" style="background-color: #3a3d46">Feature 1</div>
  </li>
  <div style="align:center; padding-left: 40%; padding-right: 40%;"><input type="text" id="package_price1" class="form-control plan-price" placeholder="4,99" formControlName="package_price"></div>

  <li class="plan-action">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning">Publish</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey Abrar, thanks for you help, I added your code, hopefully adjusted it correctly, maybe you want to take a look at it. however it is still not working :/

Comment: when I load the page it looks like this (https://puu.sh/wdLFZ/84f3f70fe2.png) , when I hit the edit button it looks like this (http://puu.sh/wdLTX/25406d2836.png)

Comment: Can you please replace `packageToEdit==tier`, with `packageToEdit.id==tier.id`

Comment: Did this: http://puu.sh/wdMFY/971172baeb.png
Ended up with: http://puu.sh/wdMHx/63e309637f.png and an error

Comment: Add the opposite logical condition i.e. `packageToEdit.id != tier.id` in the show edit mode section

Comment: When I do this: 
<ul [hidden]="!editMode || tierToEdit==tier" class="pricing-table-edit">
I start with http://puu.sh/wdMTp/8fe5ed3303.png and clicked edit on the first tier I get  http://puu.sh/wdMZH/334f842b81.png

Comment: It is due to the `[hidden]` property added to the `ul`. I think it would be better if you remove the `[hidden]` altogether and show/hide editable fields with conditions attached to `*ngIf`

Comment: Glad to know its working alright. Please mark the answer as correct, it will be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146118/discussion-between-junior-dn-and-abrar).

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is when you click to edit one of the tiers, pass in the tier into the edit function.

Then set a variable like `selectedTier` to be set to that tier or id/name of some sort associated with that tier.

Then you can match that `selectedTier` to the tier in your `ngFor`.

And then for hiding all but the selected one use `[hidden]="selectedTier != tier"`

Comment: I don't exactly understand the third and the last part or how that would work :/

Answer (score 0):

I would assign an ID to the section and in each section trigger its own editMode in ID instead of using the "this" class descriptor.